# Carpet plot with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have to create a [carpet plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_plot) (or raster plot) with MATLAB. This plot represents the hourly electric consumption along a year.

In my actual implementation I have a m x n matrix (m is the hours in a day, n the days in a year) containing the consumption values. In order to obtain the carpet plot I use the `surf` function setting `view(0,-90)` .

The problem is that MATLAB represent each "cell" of the surface with a color that is related with the interpolation of the 4 consumption values around that "cell", whereas I need that each cell of the surface represent a single value of the matrix.

Is there a way to obtain, with MATLAB, what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`surf` is for making 3-dimensional surface plots.

You want a 2-dimensional heat map - try looking at the output from `help imagesc` and `help image`.

Comment: Not only for 3D since the built-in `spectrogram` uses exactly the same trick as in the question.